Retrieve iProduct and iSerialNumber from connected USB device
I have a PCB with an MCU that has a USB peripheral on it connected to a PC and I'm writing a UI to work with it. The USB port is configured in the device as a Comm port, so it looks like "COMx" when connected. I'd like my device to determine if it's the correct COM port by looking at the iSerialNumber and iProduct strings in the descriptor block. I can already find all the Comm ports out of the USB device list using these two functions:
    public string[] FindAllPorts()
    {
        List<string> ports = new List<string>();

        foreach (ManagementObject obj in FindPorts())
        {
            try
            {
                if (obj["Caption"].ToString().Contains("(COM"))
                {
                    string ComName = ParseCommName(obj);
                    if (ComName != null)
                    {
                        ports.Add(ComName);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }

        return ports.ToArray();
    }


    static ManagementObject[] FindPorts()
    {
        try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity");
            List<ManagementObject> objects = new List<ManagementObject>();

            foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
            {
                objects.Add(obj);
            }

            return objects.ToArray();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return new ManagementObject[] { };
        }
    }

and I can find the Name (or manufacturer, description, etc.) like this:
    public List<string> ListPortsByName()
    {
        List<string> nameList = new List<string>();

        foreach (ManagementObject obj in FindPorts())
        {
            try
            {
                if (obj["Caption"].ToString().Contains("(COM"))
                    nameList.Add(obj["Name"].ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
        return nameList;
    }

but replacing "Name" with "iProduct" does not give me the product string, so there must be another way to get the string descriptor block and extract from that.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

I'd like my device to determine if it's the correct COM port by looking at the iSerialNumber and iProduct strings in the descriptor block: What does this mean? In order to have useful information in Win32_PnPEntity, one usually has to install a driver from the manufacturer. If one doesn't exist, you may be able to write your own.

The following may be of interest: Get started with drivers on Windows

@user246821 After I get a list of com ports (and obviously know the management object I grabbed it from) I'd like to query the device and retrieve the iProduct and iSterialNumer strings from the descriptor block. These all use the standard Microsoft CDC driver.

I should say unless there is something special about them (like, say an FTDI chip) they use the standard Microsoft CDC USB driver. Also, when I say "query the device" I mean query the USB device that has enumerated as a com port to get endpoint data, not the data stream from the comm port.
